# Can I use Vue without require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am just learning JS and Vue.JS and would not like have any overhead like NodeJS, npm etc at start. I want to some simple code.

The [docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) says that I need:
`Add vue and vue-resource to your package.json, then npm install, then add these lines in your code:`

But could I simply do:

```
var Vue = ('vue');
Vue.use('vue-resource');
```

or like it:

```
var App = new Vue ({
   el: '#app',
  data:
    {
      currentView: 'guestmenu'
    }
  })


Vue.use('vue-resource');
```

Am I right understand that it's extend Vue instance with `vue-resource` ?

Comment: You can use `Vue` without npm..that's just a package manager.. but you will have to fetch the extra libraries manually, which is some work. `npm` also would be required if you are `grunting or gulping` your assets.

Comment: Just add the CDN script tags to your html.. No setup needed.

Comment: Yes you can. If you use webpack, use ```externals : {
        'vue'           : 'Vue'
    }``` and then call it ```var Vue = require('vue');```

Comment: you can also use [httpVueLoader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) to load `.vue` files

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to play around with Vue and not have to worry about setting up package.json file, maybe try something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously you need to download vue.min.js and vue-resource.min.js and put them in the relative directories to your HTML file.